# PDO There is no active transaction

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

One of my class files has been spitting out the "There is no active transaction" warning when creating some records. It is the only one doing it and I can't figure out why because all my queries are executing successfully.

My php_errors log has given me zero insight to the issue, nor have any of the other related questions provided any solutions.

```
    try {
        App::$DB->beginTransaction();

        $rQuery = App::$DB->prepare("INSERT INTO `Cervidae` (`".implode('`, `',array_keys($aSQL))  ."`) VALUES (".implode(",",$aPlaceholders).")");
        $rQuery->execute(array_values($aSQL));

        $this->_Cervid_ID = App::$DB->lastInsertId();

        if (is_array($aData["Treatments"])) {
            foreach ($aData["Treatments"] as $sTreatmentName => $sTreatmentData) {
                $oTreatmentToCervid = new TreatmentToCervid(array("Treatment_ID" => $sTreatmentData["Treatment_ID"], "Cervid_ID" => $this->_Cervid_ID, "CreatedBy" => $aSQL["CreatedBy"], "UpdatedBy" => $aSQL["UpdatedBy"], "Dose" => $sTreatmentData["TreatmentDose"]), "NEW");
            }
        }

        $oHerdSize = App::getFlat(self::get(array("COUNT(Cervidae.Cervid_ID) AS HerdSize"),array("Cervidae.Herd_ID = $nHerdID","Cervidae.IsActive = 1")));
        $rQuery = App::$DB->prepare("UPDATE `Herds` SET `HerdSize` = ".$oHerdSize->HerdSize." WHERE `Herd_ID` = ".$nHerdID);
        $rQuery->execute();

        App::$DB->commit();

        $this->__construct($this->_Cervid_ID, 'ID');

    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        App::$DB->rollBack();
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Do you know where the error comes from - commit or rollback? If the last line of your code in the try block (after commit) throws an exception then the catch will try to rollback when there is no longer a transaction.

Comment: This does seem to be the case. If I comment out my construct line, I receive no warning. The issue lied in the fact that I began adding support for additional columns that were to be soon added to my table. This caused my construct to fail since those columns had not yet existed.

Comment: I should have put that as an answer!!! Just move the offending line out & into another try-catch block. I always aim to have the commit as the last statement in the try-catch just for this reason - or have a flag to indicate the transaction has been committed.

Comment: catching exception just to throw it does not seem like a good idea. Use finally if u need such behavior.